# Tabela Dimensional/Fato no R

Tags: r

Atualmente tenho 4 data.frames que possuem ID e os outros dados, e com isso pretendo usar modelo dimensional(conhecido como estrela) para criar uma tabela fato com todos os IDs. Porém a unica forma que pensei em desenvolver isso foi criar manualmente todos os vínculos mais de forma muito não eficaz. Existe alguma biblioteca ou uma forma usual de criar tabelas fatos no R?

```
## Exempo
di_tabela1 = c(id_1, nome, endereco)
di_tabela2 = c(id_2, descricao)
di_tabela3 = c(id_3, local, cep)
di_tabela4 = c(id_4, zz, xx, codigo)

## Forma grotesca, so jogando os ids
fato_tabela = c(id_1,id_2,id_3,id_4)
```

Comment: eu não entendi direito oq vc precisa, mas tem a função expand.grid se vc precisa de todas as combinações de alguma coisa, tenta escrever um reprex com um resultado esperado pf

Comment: Na verdade, quero criar um novo data.frame (fato_tabela) com os IDs, das outras tabelas, pq vou gravar isso em um banco de dados Postgres, e a forma que vou gravar esses IDs, precisa ser de uma forma que respeite as regras de integração entre as tabelas. Pesquisei bastante sobre e não encontrei alguma biblioteca focada em tabelas fato, estou pensando em criar todas as regras de forma manual mesmo(com ifs, mutate, etc)

Comment: mas vc precisa da combinação única de ids's?

Comment: Isso, porque será realizado no BI analises, e ele irá fazer as referencias pelos IDs, e se eu criar essa tabela fato, terá um desempenho maior nas consultas.

Comment: a ok, vc tem esses df em alguma lista ou tibble? Por isso que eu pedi o reprex da pra resolver esse problema bem rápido mas sem o formator dos seus dados fica difícil